# Use external css font with kotlin-styled

Tags: css, kotlin

I have created a kotlin react app using `kotlin-react` and I'm using `kotlin-styled` for CSS styling.

I want to change the font of a custom text component with a custom font from Google Fonts. With `.css` files I would have done the following:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap');

.text {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
```

How can I achieve something similar with `kotlin-styled`. I have looked for a `import` or `url` function but It doesn't exist. Also, they do not have any documentation on external fonts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is `CSSBuilder#import` available since pre.210, so what you can do is:

```
CSSBuilder().apply {
   import("url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap')")
    
   fontFamily = "'Nunito', sans-serif"
}
```

Comment: this is no longer relevant. anyone know the latest solution?